# Web API + Client Architecture

Tags: architecture, api-design

We're building:

1. A bunch of services exposed through a web API.
2. A mobile app and a browser app.

Is it common practice for the apps to respond to their own conduit servers that end up talking to the API services? We're going to be setting up a reverse proxy - is it enough to directly hit our APIs (instead of setting up a conduit)? This is definitely a general architecture question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "conduit", but a lot depends on how complete and hardened your APIs are.  Do they already handle things like authentication, abuse detection/control, SSL, versioning, etc...

There are companies that specialize in providing this "middleware" of APIs ([Apigee](http://apigee.com/), [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/), and many others).  Your reverse proxy is a start, and is probably good enough to get going with (at least you do things like terminate your SSL, and lock down your API servers behind a firewall).  If you make your API services stateless, you will probably be able to add new layers at a later date without too much pain and complexity.